# How to better express "Dwayne Johnson has been given more footage than Jason Statham in the movie"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, vocabulary, expression-choice

By footage I do not mean on screen time. I mean Dwayne Jhonson has been given scenes that show him to be better than Jason Statham. Although both were given roughly the same on screen time, Dwayne was given more scenes and heroic stunts what would appeal to audience.

How does one say that in a sentence? May be more concise one.

Comment: "How does one say that in a sentence?" The way you did works.

Comment: @Lawrence Doesn't "footage" mean on screen time?

Comment: I was referring to your sentence "Although both were given roughly the same on screen time, Dwayne was given more scenes and heroic stunts [t]hat would appeal to audience."

Comment: @Lawrence oh well yes but it's too verbose. Isn't it?

Comment: Whether it's "too verbose" is subjective. What context are you thinking of, in which that would sound too verbose?

Comment: @Lawrence I was just wondering if there is more concise alternative?

Comment: I don't think there's a term that exactly means "more appealing scenes and better heroic stunts". You could say something more generic, such as "in better light", but what you've got says what you want precisely.

Comment: @Lawrence I think "in better light" would work too. Thanks.

Comment: Probably you should express it "Johnson".

Comment: @HotLicks you are right.

Comment: Idiomatically you could say "Johnson has a juicier role than Stratham." Or you could say "Johnson's role lets him showcase his action-hero talents, while Stratham's gives him less room to shine."

Comment: How about "The Rock covers paper."

Answer (score 1):

Dwayne Johnson was given a more *dynamic* part in the movie than Jason Statham.

Dwayne Johnson's part was better tailored to show off his talents than that of Jason Statham.

Dwayne Johnson's character *stole the show*.

Take your pick.